# I upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04: Now neither Network Manager nor Wicd work. How do I get internet connection?

Tags: networking, apt, upgrade, network-manager, wicd

I have a 10 years old Lenovo B590, on which Network Manager doesn't seem to work. I replaced it with Wicd and all for fine for years. Now I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. Wicd disappeared. I tried re-install it downloading the package from another computer, but didn't manage.
INPUT: `sudo apt install wicd`

OUTPUT: `E: package 'wicd' has no installation candidate`

I read other posts, and it seems this is due to some Python issue. I don't really understand it.
Is there any software that I could use as a substitute of Network Manager, and Wicd?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that NetworkManager was not enabled. I unmasked, enabled, and started it. It seems to be working fine right now. I am connected to internet again.
I suspected that NetworkManager could be disabled because I had read it should be working in parallel to Wicd. I then looked up how to start/enable it. In the end, I adapted the suggestions from this other post: https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/ubuntu-network-manager/

COMMANDS
`sudo systemctl unmask NetworkManager`
`sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager`
`sudo systemctl start NetworkManager`

I guess this means that the newer version of NetworkManager seems to work now on my computer (it certainly didn't before). Instead, I have not managed to install Wicd. However, I just needed internet connection, so that the issue is solved. Thanks!

Comment: This answer could be more useful if you explain why you suspected masking and the steps you took to confirm the problem. Proper formatting of the commands would help a lot, too. When a future reader sees this answer, they won't know if this answer will solve their problem.